# Create a reusable file decoder with different Models

Tags: swift

I can have multiple models and they could be within an array or not, for example:

`[Model1]` or `Model` or `[Model2]` or `[String: [Model2]]`

This is my attempt to reuse the same function:

```
/// Decode existing file on disk
func decodeFileStoredInDisk(modelToDecode: Any, fileName: String, fileExtension: String) -> Any? {
    var decodedFile: Any = []
    
    do {
        let fileURL = try FileManager.default
            .url(for: .applicationSupportDirectory, in: .userDomainMask, appropriateFor: nil, create: false)
            .appendingPathComponent(fileName + fileExtension)
        
        let data = try Data(contentsOf: fileURL)
        decodedFile = try JSONDecoder().decode(modelToDecode.self, from: data)
        
    } catch {
        print(" Error decoding file disk: \(error)")
    }
    
    return decodedFile
}
```

The problem I'm having is that it complains:

```
Cannot convert value of type 'Any' to expected argument type 'Any.Protocol'
```

I tried the suggestion:

```
decodedFile = try JSONDecoder().decode(modelToDecode.self as! Any.Protocol, from: data)
```

but still complains with:

```
Protocol 'Any' as a type cannot conform to 'Decodable'
```

The error is in `modelToDecode`, if I put the exact model: `[Model1]` it likes that.

How can I use any type there?

Comment: Sorry I'm not following with "use a generic type contained to Decodable" What do you mean? @vadian

Comment: See the answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The decoder needs to know the static type therefore `Any` is not supported at all.

Use a generic type constrained to `Decodable` like this

```
func decodeFileStoredInDisk<T : Decodable>(modelToDecode: T.Type, fileName: String, fileExtension: String) throws -> T {
    let fileURL = try FileManager.default
        .url(for: .applicationSupportDirectory, in: .userDomainMask, appropriateFor: nil, create: false)
        .appendingPathComponent(fileName)
        .appendingPathExtension(fileExtension)
        
    let data = try Data(contentsOf: fileURL)
    return try JSONDecoder().decode(T.self, from: data)
}
```

And the function passes a possible error to the caller.

Comment: Do you mind explaining how to encode it? I'm facing the same/different issue, before I can pass in the type, but now encoding it I need the data and I can't say `Any` because it complains like above :/

Comment: It says: `Type 'T.Type' cannot conform to 'Encodable'` I tried this: `func encodeDataToDeviceStorage<T : Encodable>(dataToStore: T.Type) {`

Comment: You don't need the type. `encodeFileStoredInDisk<U : Encodable>(modelToEncode: U, fileName: String, fileExtension: String) throws` and encode just `modelToEncode`. And once again stop trying to use `Any`

Comment: Ohhh I see, now it worked, I was using T instead of U, honestly I'm confused with those. Thanks now it works :)

Comment: I just wanted to make clear that's a different generic type.